# ClearML How to get configurable hyperparameters?

Tags: devops, mlops, clearml, trains

How do I get args like epochs to show up in the UI configuration panel under hyperparameters? I want to be able to change number of epochs and learning rate from within the UI.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. for better help, you need to provide better information. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `argparse` - ClearML will auto-magically log all parameters in the task's configuration section (under hyper-parameters section) - see [this](https://github.com/allegroai/clearml/blob/master/examples/frameworks/keras/keras_tensorboard.py#L56) example. You can also just connect any dictionary (see [this](https://github.com/allegroai/clearml/blob/master/examples/frameworks/ignite/cifar_ignite.py#L23) example)

Comment: This is how it is. Also, let me clarify the issue I faced. Basically when I create task, its in view only draft state because that is how you created it. You can change the values of the hyperparameters when you clone a task that exists or reset one.

Comment: That's actually by design - when you create a task, you run it locally, and ClearML records it. Since it's a "development" run, the default is for it to be "read-only" in the UI, in order to reflect the exact parameters used when running it.
When cloning it, you're basically creating a variation of that run, which makes sense when you want to edit it and run it remotely.
Of course, as you've said, you can always reset it and edit - it's your "override" in case you decide to :)